# Adding reCaptcha in wordpress protected page form

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a reCaptcha verification on a form that is displayed on a password protected page. I tried different plugins and non have displaying option on password protected pages. 
I found a way to display the reCaptcha field on the page with a customizing form function that i added in the functions.php file from the theme folder.But i don't know how to make it verify the reCaptcha before submiting the information.

```
function my_custom_js() {
echo '
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 <script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   }
 </script>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_js');
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'custom_password_form' );
function custom_password_form() {
global $post;
$label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
$o = '<form class="protected-post-form" id="form1" action="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?action=postpass" method="post" >
' . __( "This is a password protected page. Please enter the password below:" ) . '
<label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password"  />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
<button
class="g-recaptcha button"
data-sitekey="6Ld2wVIUAAAAAPnw70ZMDA9Auxu_Tl1rqV-W4kxv"
data-callback="onSubmit">
Submit
</button>
</form>
';
return $o;
}
```

I also get a error message:

```
Invalid reCAPTCHA client id: null
    at Object.Cr [as reset] (recaptcha__en.js:391)
    at (index):1158
    at wp_recaptchaLoadCallback ((index):1160)
    at recaptcha__en.js:394
    at ir (recaptcha__en.js:378)
    at recaptcha__en.js:394
    at recaptcha__en.js:405
```

I'm stuck. I don't know how to proceed next.
Thank you for reading this. If anyone can point me in the right direction it will mean the world to me.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert but you could try to add this to your header.php

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

And then you can call the js script with a function in function.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','password_js');
function password_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'password', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/password.js');
}
```